# Where is information about Storage Pools and Virtual Disks stored in Windows Server?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, azure, storage-spaces

Environment: Azure, Windows 2012 R2 VMs.

I've created a Storage Pool of 3 disks (VHDs), striped, a Virtual Disk on top of it, and a volume. Then I've stopped this VM, detached these VHDs and attached them to another brand new VM. When second VM started, the Storage Pool and Virtual Disk appeared automatically, and even a volume was automatically created (with different volume letter, but anyway).

So, where is information about Storage Pool is stored? On one of the disks, on all of them (duplicated) ?

Answer (score 4):

In Windows Server, Storage pool & space informations are stored on every physical (or VHD in your case) disks as metadata in a "Database"

There is a copie of the "Storage Space database" on every drive of the pool.

Unfortunately, there are very few public available documents about this :

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11382.storage-spaces-frequently-asked-questions-faq.aspx?PageIndex=2#What_happens_to_Storage_Spaces_when_moving_physical_disks_between_servers

http://www.storage-spaces-recovery.com/storage-spaces-recovery-manual.pdf

regards

Stanislas